# Apply .toggle() method only in clicked DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and I would want like to know how to apply the .toggle() method only in clicked DIV instead of the all DIVs of the page.

Can anyone help me?

**PS: I need implement in the JQuery version 1.4**

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="card.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#toggle2').live("click", function() {
                    $('.toggle2').toggle();
                    return false;
                });
            });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="card">
    <a href="#" id="toggle2">Switch Text Toggle</a><br />
    <p class="toggle2">FRONT 1</p>
    <p class="toggle2" style="display:none;">BACK 1</p>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <a href="#" id="toggle2">Switch Text Toggle</a><br />
    <p class="toggle2">FRONT 2</p>
    <p class="toggle2" style="display:none;">BACK 2</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    $('#toggle2').live("click", function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.toggle2').toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

ID's are unique, and this will probably only work on the first occurence of `#toggle`, so you'll need to use classes there as well.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/j5nMY/)